# KNearest Neighbors in sklearn - ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to do a k nearest neighbors prediction on some text recognition data I found on the UCI Machine Learning Database. (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Letter+Recognition)

I cross validated the data and tested for accuracy with no issues but I can't run the classifier.predict(). Can anyone shed light on why I'm getting this error? I read up on the curse of dimensionality on the sklearn site but I'm having trouble actually fixing my code.

My code so far is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, neighbors

df = pd.read_csv('KMeans_letter_recog.csv')    

X = np.array(df.drop(['Letter'], 1))
y = np.array(df['Letter'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2) #20% data used

clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
accuracy = clf.score(X_test, y_test) #test
print(accuracy) #this works fine

example = np.array([7,4,3,2,4,5,3,6,7,4,2,3,5,6,8,4])
example = X.reshape(len(example), -1)

prediction = clf.predict(example)
print(prediction) #error
```

df.head() produces:

```
 Letter   x-box   y-box   box_width   box_height   on_pix   x-bar_mean  \
0      T       2       8           3            5        1            8   
1      I       5      12           3            7        2           10   
2      D       4      11           6            8        6           10   
3      N       7      11           6            6        3            5   
4      G       2       1           3            1        1            8   

    y-bar_mean   x2bar_mean   y2bar_mean   xybar_mean   x2y_mean   xy2_mean  \
0           13            0            6            6         10          8   
1            5            5            4           13          3          9   
2            6            2            6           10          3          7   
3            9            4            6            4          4         10   
4            6            6            6            6          5          9   

    x-ege   xegvy   y-ege   yegvx  
0       0       8       0       8  
1       2       8       4      10  
2       3       7       3       9  
3       6      10       2       8  
4       1       7       5      10
```

My error feed as as such:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jai_j\Desktop\Python Projects\K Means ML.py", line 31, in <module>
    prediction = clf.predict(example)
  File "C:\Users\jai_j\Desktop\Python Projects\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\classification.py", line 145, in predict
    neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)
  File "C:\Users\jai_j\Desktop\Python Projects\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py", line 381, in kneighbors
    for s in gen_even_slices(X.shape[0], n_jobs)
  File "C:\Users\jai_j\Desktop\Python Projects\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 758, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "C:\Users\jai_j\Desktop\Python Projects\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 608, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "C:\Users\jai_j\Desktop\Python Projects\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 571, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "C:\Users\jai_j\Desktop\Python Projects\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 109, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "C:\Users\jai_j\Desktop\Python Projects\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 326, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "C:\Users\jai_j\Desktop\Python Projects\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "C:\Users\jai_j\Desktop\Python Projects\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 131, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "sklearn\neighbors\binary_tree.pxi", line 1294, in sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.BinaryTree.query (sklearn\neighbors\kd_tree.c:11325)
ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension
```

Thank you in advance for any help, I'll keep searching for an answer in the meantime

Comment: My guess is that the training data you're trying to feed in doesn't match prediction dimensions, most likely the n dimension. If you've got 10 features and you pass in 9 that could be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I checked the features; there are 16 features and I made sure I was using the same number when predicting. I still get the error unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problems are that you are not reshaping `example` and that you are reshaping to incorrect dimensions. You are reshaping your `X` array to be `(16, N)`, where `N` is the number of observations in `X`.

As a result, when you try to predict on `example`, you end up using your classifier to predict on `X` reshaped to have `N` columns, instead of 16 columns as in the one you trained on.

It seems you want to predict on your single example, so you should reshape it instead of `X`. Presumably, you want `example = example.reshape(1, -1)` instead of `example = X.reshape(len(example), -1)`.

Initially, you create `example` with shape `(16,)`. You should reshape it to be `(1, 16)`, by using `(1, -1)` as the dimensions. This will result in an array with shape `(1, 16)`, which fits your classifier.

To be clear, try changing your code to this:

```
example = np.array([7,4,3,2,4,5,3,6,7,4,2,3,5,6,8,4])
example = example.reshape(1, -1)

prediction = clf.predict(example)
print(prediction) # shouldn't error anymore
```

Answer (score 0):

I isolate individual commandline , it is the xxxx.predict(example) problem instead of X.reshape(x,x)----- typing error or .reshape(x,x)

Comment: i am facing same problems while practising  code  ---clf = neighbors.KneighborsClassifier()  >>> clf.fit(X_train, y_train) >>> accuracy = clf.score(x_test, y_test) >>>> print(accuracy) >>> example_measures = np.array([[4,2,1,1,1,2,3,2,1],[4,2,1,1,1,2,3,2,1]]) >>example_measures = example_measures.reshape(1, -1) >>> prediction = clf.predict(example_measures)

Answer (score 0):

Also, instead of:

```
example = example.reshape(1,-1),
```

an alternative is:

```
example = example[np.newaxis, :]
```